# Displaying chess pieces in unicode not working

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicalDisplay extends JFrame implements Display{
    public void showPiecesOnBoard(Piece[][] data) {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        setSize(400,400);
        setTitle("chess");
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout (8,8));
        JButton[][] squares = new JButton[8][8];

        for(int y=7; y>=0; y--){
            for(int x=0; x<8; x++){
                squares[x][y] = new JButton();

                if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
                    squares[x][y].setBackground(Color.black);
                } 
                else {
                    squares[x][y].setBackground(Color.white);
                }  
                //if piece is present print out the unicode corresponding to piece
                if(data[x][y]!=null){
                    if (data[x][y].toString() == "k")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2654");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "q")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2655");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "r")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2656");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "b")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2657");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "n")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2658");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "p")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2659");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString() == "K")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265A");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "Q")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265B");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "R")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265C");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "B")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265D");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "N")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265E");
                    else if(data[x][y].toString() == "P")
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265F");
                }
                contentPane.add(squares[x][y]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my code I am using eclipse and have made sure to run as utf8 in the common settings.

But it still doesn't print out any of the unicode characters on top of the buttons.

Although if i just make it print out the string at that position it will print out the letters on top of the buttons correctly.

So how would i go about making the unicode characters display on top of the buttons?

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicalDisplay extends JFrame implements Display{
    public void showPiecesOnBoard(Piece[][] data) {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        setSize(800,800);
        setTitle("chess");
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout (8,8));
        JButton[][] squares = new JButton[8][8];

        for(int y=7; y>=0; y--){
            for(int x=0; x<8; x++){
                squares[x][y] = new JButton();

                if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
                    squares[x][y].setBackground(Color.black);
                } 
                else {
                    squares[x][y].setBackground(Color.white);
                }  
                //if piece is present print out the unicode corresponding to piece
                if(data[x][y]!=null){
                    if (data[x][y].toString().equals("k"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2654");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("q"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2655");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("r"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2656");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("b"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2657");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("n"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2658");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("p"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u2659");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("K"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265A");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("Q"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265B");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("R"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265C");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("B"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265D");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("N"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265E");
                    else if (data[x][y].toString().equals("P"))
                        squares[x][y].setText("\u265F");
                }
                contentPane.add(squares[x][y]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `setSize()`? Why not `pack()`?

Comment: `but i cant accept my answer for 2 days` - this is not an answer. It is a piece of code. We don't know what is different from your original code and the code you just posted. Don't expect people to compare every line. Tell people what you changed.